# Heroku React & Express.js Release problems

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I have released a website that I am working on and can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

In my App.jsx file I have a router as follows:

```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/services" element={<Services />} />
          <Route path="/custom" element={<CustomQuote />} />
          <Route path="/consultation" element={<Consultation />} />
          <Route path="/contactUs" element={<ContactUs />} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

and then I have the express server app.js that also has its own API routes example:

```
    app.get("/getSomeData", async (req, res) => {
     try {
        const someDataCount= await SomeData.countDocuments({});
        res.json(someDataCount);
     } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send("An error occurred while fetching the custom quote count.");
     }
    });
```

The problem is, when I click on the nav bar and navigate through the website it works perfectly fine. All the routes work as "www.domain.com/about" and the about page would show. But as soon as I try to refresh the page it just says "Not found", this I assume is because it is trying to use the API to retrieve the data from a call matching "/about".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNxvB.png)

How would I fix this to make the website "know" that there is a front-end with front-end routes and a back-end with back-end routes

I have tried renaming the routes to "/api/route" in the app.js express server. But this didn't work as it still did not "know" about the front-end routes

When typing the [www.domain.com/someapicall](http://www.domain.com/someapicall) it returns the data, so the express app works perfectly fine.

I have hosted it on heroku.

I have already tried to rename the app.js routes, but didn't work as expected.
I have released the page as a static website (so used npm run build) to create a build and release that to the site.